# Отсортировать буквы в словах в алфавитном порядке С++

Tags: c++, сортировка, list

Дана не пустая последовательность слов , вывести на экран все буквы в алфавитном порядке.
Я вытянул из строки сами слова и поместил в список (его нужно использовать) , но не знаю как отсортировать буквы в словах , вот код :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    string s, d = ",.";
    cout << "Введите слова : "<<endl;

    cin >> s;

    list <string>  MyList ;

    int b, e=0;

    while ((b = s.find_first_not_of(d, e)) != s.npos) {
        e = s.find_first_of(d, b);
        MyList.push_back(s.substr(b, e - b));
        b = e;
    }

    cout << "Список слов : "<<endl;

    copy(MyList.begin(), MyList.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Вы читаете одно-единственное слово. Так и нужно? Слова же могут разделяться и пробелами...

Comment: ну и зачем  запихивать эти слова в какой то контейнер?

Comment: По сути: если есть слово `string word;`, то отсортировать его буквы - `sort(word.begin(),word.end());`

Comment: Слова отделены запятыми , это условие программы , поместил в контейнер для того чтобы убрать разделители , а если сортировать саму строку , то после сортировки останутся все разделители в виде запятых и точки